# "Unknown" control in Toolbox

Tags: excel, userform

Was working on a new project today when I noticed this "Unknown" control type in the toolbox - I haven't seen this before. Does anyone know what this is?

[image: Unknown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "RefEdit" control.
When it's active, and using the mouse, it allows the user to select a cell, range of cells (by holding mouse or with Shift), or Multiple Ranges of Cells (with Ctrl). (arrow keys do not work). The selection can be on a different sheet to the one the control is on.

It returns a string that represents the range selected, I.e.
`Sheet1!$A$1`,
`Sheet1!$A$2:$B$2` or
`Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$2,Sheet1!$A$3:$C$3`
etc, respectively.

[bettersolutions.com](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/controls/refedit.htm) has probably the most info I can find on this.

As the user can type into this control, it Does Not necessarily return a Valid range!

Interestingly, the "Unknown" control type tooltip is probably because of https://peltiertech.com/unspecified-painfully-frustrating-error/ due to apparent general RefEdit flakiness: https://peltiertech.com/refedit-control-alternative/